# Find and rename a string in a file using a batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I have a node.js file with a variable declared as `DIR="C:/myfile.js"`. I want to find the variable `DIR` and rename it to `"C:/myfile2.js"` using a batch file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. This worked and I could read bat files.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/batchfile